# Strange behavior with algorithm to find combination bits

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to get all the unique combinations of bits(real interesting..I know..zzz).  Basically it works well for small numbers like 10 bits with 3 unique or 100 bits and 4 unique.  I am testing it at scale but something odd happens when I use 200 bits and 30 items..I get nothing.  I've tried to debug the code and can't see why.

I'm using all longs so I'm not sure why, are bits somehow limited or is this a problem with my math?  Also, is what I'm doing possible for very large number of bits or is there some limit(i.e. the sun burning out before my program is done)? Ideally I would like to get 30 unique bits from a list of 2000..This approach has been the only that exceeds 100 but I don't know its limit.

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Combinatorics {

    static final class CombinationsIterator implements Iterator<Long> {
        private int n;
        private int k;
        private long next;

        public CombinationsIterator(int n, int k) {
            this.n = n;
            this.k = k;
            next = (1L << k) - 1;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return (next & (1L << n)) == 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Long next() {
            long result = next;
            long x = next;
            long u = x & -x;
            long v = u + x;
            x = v + (((v ^ x) / u) >> 2);
            next = x;
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    }

    static final class PermutationsIterator implements Iterator<List<Integer>> {
        int n;
        int k;
        int nPk;
        List<Integer> elements;
        int i;
        List<Integer> next;

        public PermutationsIterator(int n, int k) {
            this.n = n;
            this.k = k;

            nPk = permute(n, k);

            List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                elements.add(i);
            this.elements = Collections.unmodifiableList(elements);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() { return i < nPk; }

        @Override
        public List<Integer> next() {
            List<Integer> next = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            List<Integer> notNext = new ArrayList<Integer>(elements);
            int r = i;
            int np = nPk;
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                np /= n - j;
                next.add(notNext.remove(r / np));
                r %= np;
            }
            i++;
            return next;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    }

    public static long toCombination(List<Integer> permutation) {
        long combination = 0;
        for (int i : permutation)
            combination |= (1L << i);
        return combination;
    }

    public static List<Integer> toPermutation(long combination) {
        List<Integer> permutation = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        long combinationRemaining = combination;
        int i = 0;
        while (combinationRemaining > 0) {
            if ((combinationRemaining & 1) > 0) {
                permutation.add(i);
            }
            combinationRemaining >>= 1;
            i++;
        }
        return permutation;
    }

    public static SortedMap<Integer, Integer> multiplicitiesOf(List<Integer> multiset) {
        SortedMap<Integer, Integer> multiplicities = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for (Integer k : multiset) {
            Integer v = multiplicities.get(k);
            v = (v == null) ? 1 : (v + 1);
            multiplicities.put(k, v);
        }
        return multiplicities;
    }

    public static Iterator<Long> combinationsIterator(int n, int k) {
        return new CombinationsIterator(n, k);
    }

    public static Iterator<List<Integer>> permutationsIterator(int n, int k) {
        return new PermutationsIterator(n, k);
    }

    public static int factorial(int n) {
        int result = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            result *= i;
        return result;
    }

    public static int permute(int n, int k) {
        int result = 1;
        for (int i = n - k + 1; i <= n; i++)
            result *= i;
        return result;
    }

    public static int choose(int n, int k) {
        return permute(n, k) / factorial(k);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Starting");
        for (Iterator<Long> it = combinationsIterator(200, 2); it.hasNext(); ) {
            long next = it.next();
            System.out.format("%d\t%10s\n", next, Long.toBinaryString(next));
        }

    }
}
```

In the `main` method changing `combinationsIterator(200, 2);` generates the strange behavior(10,3 gives the correct result very quickly, even 100,5..but as the number gets higher it just doesn't give results as opposed to taking time to process)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using a `long`, it's limited to 64 bits.  But that said,  `200` choose `30` will take you -- based on some rough back-of-the-envelope math -- a billion billion millenia to iterate through on a modern PC.

Comment: I had a feeling it was the number of bits...Is there any way to get 200/30 in a reasonable time frame or is it completely impossible? I've tried so many different ways of getting combinations and this seemed to be the most promising because it exceeded 100, but seems like a wall.

Comment: @Error_404 200 choose 30 is an insanely large number.  About 4 * 10^35.  So yeah, practically impossibly.

Comment: @Error_404 200 choose 30 is `409681705022127773530866523638950880`, impossible.

Comment: Not practical, not even if you had a supercomputer, or 1000 computers to play around with.  200 choose *3* might be feasible, but much farther above that would be ridiculous.

Comment: 10^7 is typically my rule of thumb for big-O-per-second on a standard PC these days.  Google calls that 1.29823071 × 10^18 *millenia* for 200 choose 30.  A billion billion millenia.

Comment: Sorry, just trying to take a wild shot but is there any way this is possible? Not just my approach but in general? Are there any companies in the world that use large amount of combinations for their work? ..By the way, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Not like this, no.  Because it would take them a *billion billion millenia.*  If we knew what you were actually trying to do, we might be able to help, but when you encounter a problem like this, you find a way *around*, not through.

Comment: @Error_404:  To illustrate the point further, let's presume you have a machine that could do 100 billion operations per second.  Even with *that*, it would take 129.9 quadrillion **years**.   Louis Wasserman is right - you want to find a way around this issue, and not try to spend an eternity crunching this number.

Comment: I'm trying to look for certain patterns in data. In order for me to run my statistical models against it, I need all possible combinations of it(limited by 30 items each but from a list of thousands).  I don't know if my system can find patterns without a full dataset but the full data set looks like it'll be impossible to generate. I don't want to give up but I don't know what else to try.

Comment: my specific goal is to try to study stocks, take all combinations of 30 stock portfolios in the market and then study each for risk/reward so I can say which one is the best. I feel this is impossible and I don't see a way to succeed at it now.

Comment: I may have a way forward... or is it around? My email is in my profile.

Comment: @TonyEnnis I couldn't see it on your profile.  I looked at your site as well but it redirects to your google+ page where there is no option to message you.

Comment: @TonyEnnis thanks. I emailed you(if you like you can delete your email from the post so spambots don't find you)